# OAuth2.0 authentication in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, oauth-2.0, raspberry-pi

I've managed to implement the [simpleauth](http://code.google.com/p/gae-simpleauth/) package for a basic webapp I've been working on. I now need to send data to this service from a python script running on a Raspberry Pi (the app is a "data logger" for temperature). Before I had implemented the simpleauth package, I could just POST the data and username to the site. Alas, now the response is the login page (to be expected).

If I wanted to connect to this webapp from the command line, I assume I'll need to authenticate myself. However, how would I go about doing this? I assume I'm going to need to programmatically replicate the steps taken by the browser to get a token but [I think I've tried this](http://pastebin.com/uPYMSKee) and it hasn't worked. I'm not even sure who my token provider is - my webapp, or Google?

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to authenticate on an installed or console app, you need to use `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` as the `redirect_uri` `GET` param in when you redirect the user to the login/authorization page. Once your app has been authorized, they'll be presented with a valid OAuth 2.0 code in a text box that they'll have to copy/paste into your app. Once they do that, then your app must follow the rest of the usual server-side flow (code for token exchange, etc.).